# Preventing deletion of noncurrent objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm storing backups in Cloud Storage. A desirable property of such a backup is to ensure the device being backed up cannot erase the backups, to protect against ransomware or similar threats. At the same time, it is desirable to allow the backup client to delete so old files can be pruned. (Because the backups are encrypted, it isn't possible to use lifecycle management to do this.)

The solution that immediately comes to mind is to enable object versioning and use lifecycle rules to retain object versions (deleted files) for a certain amount of time. However, I cannot see a way to allow the backup client to delete the *current* version, but not historical versions. I thought it might be possible to do this with an IAM condition, but the conditional logic doesn't seem flexible enough to parse out the object version. Is there another way I've missed?

The only other solution that comes to mind is to create a second bucket, inaccessible to the backup client, and use a Cloud Function to replicate the first bucket. The downside of that approach is the duplicate storage cost.

Comment: Could you include on your post the following lifecycle rules that you've tried which doesn't work?

Comment: As far as I can tell, lifecycle rules can be used to retain object versions but will not prevent an API user with delete permissions from explicitly deleting an old object version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this:

> However, I cannot see a way to allow the backup client to delete the current version, but not historical versions

When you delete a live object, object versioning will retain a noncurrent version of it.  When [deleting the noncurrent object version](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#delete), you will have to specify the object name along with its generation number.

Just to add, you may want to consider using a [transfer job](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#configure) to replicate your data on a separate bucket.

Either way, both approach (object versioning or replicating buckets) will incur additional storage costs.

Comment: Yeah, it looks replicating the bucket will be the only solution. The issue is precisely that the backup client could delete noncurrent versions by explicitly specifying the generation number. If the threat model is assuming a possibly malicious client (such as ransomware), the noncurrent versions need to be immutable. And thank you for the pointer to transfer jobs - I did not see that.